# jQuery on change AJAX issues

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have the following scenario:

I have a table that is populated with user data like name, surname, location and courses in a structure like the following:

```
<tr>                          
   <td data-label="First Name" class="wppb-name"><span>Mutanga</span></td>
   <td data-label="Last Name" class="wppb-name"><span>Eto Emule</span></td>         
   <td data-label="Location" class="wppb-name"><span>Somewhere</span></td> 
   <td data-label="Courses" class="wppb-name seminaria-multiselect">Course 1, Course 2, Course 3, Course 4, Course 5, Course 6</td>                    
</tr>
```

The courses are fetched in a long line of text with no separation which i dont want neither i can insert span elements manually to each course. I change it with the following jQuery snippet. This separates the courses and insert them into spans and it works.

```
$('.seminaria-multiselect').each(function() {                   
    $(this).html($(this).html().split(', ').map(function(el) {
        return '<span>' + el + '</span>';
    }));        
});
```

Now the problem is that when i apply filters (for example, filter the users for specific locations or specificcourses), it does the filtering using AJAX and it loses the 'span formatting' of the above snippet.

I understand that this can be solved using the on() method, something like this:

```
$(document).on('change', '.seminaria-multiselect', function() { 
    $('.seminaria-multiselect').each(function() {                   
        $(this).html($(this).html().split(', ').map(function(el) {
            return '<span>' + el + '</span>';
        }));        
    });
});
```

This snippet however does not work properly all by itself. When the page is loaded, the text is not separated into spans neither after applying filters.

If i keep both the snippets like so:

```
$('.seminaria-multiselect').each(function() {                   
    $(this).html($(this).html().split(', ').map(function(el) {
        return '<span>' + el + '</span>';
    }));        
});         
$(document).on('change', '.seminaria-multiselect', function() { 
    $('.seminaria-multiselect').each(function() {                   
        $(this).html($(this).html().split(', ').map(function(el) {
            return '<span>' + el + '</span>';
        }));        
    });
});
```

then it applies the span separation on page load but filtering still doesn't produce the result i want.

Q1) What should i correct in order to make it work?
Q2) Is there a more efficient way to do this? Is it necessary to keep both snippets (the first one when the page loads and 2nd one for when it filters)

I thank you very much for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger on change event manually on page load in order to make it work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){         
$(document).on('change', '.seminaria-multiselect', function() { 
    $('.seminaria-multiselect').each(function() {                   
        $(this).html($(this).html().split(', ').map(function(el) {
            return '<span>' + el + '</span>';
        }));        
    });
});
$(".seminaria-multiselect").trigger("change");
});
```

Comment: It would be cleaner to put the contents of the change event in a function and call that in both places.

Comment: Hello, this still does not work, plus it messes with the original markup producing somethings like <td class="wppb-name seminaria-multiselect"><span><span><span><span><span>Course 1</span><span>Course 2</span><span>Course 3</span></span></span></span></span></td>